# SQL Server: Cannot connect remotely after changing server name successfully

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

My local computer's operating system is Windows 10 Professional.

We have a remote server named **XXXXAD01**. Its operating system is Windows Server 2016 Standard. It is part of a Domain ISYYYY.ZZZZZ. It has 2016 SQL Server installed as MSSQLSERVER (default instance).

*I renamed the remote server's SQL Server to **XXXXAT01** using this procedure:*

- I made remote desktop connection to it.
- Inside I open SQL Server Management Studio 18 and connect to the
  server using Windows Authentication.
- Execute `sp_dropserver XXXXAD01; go` command.
- Execute `sp_addserver XXXXAT01, local; go` command.
- I open SQL Server Configuration Manager and restart the SQL Server
  service (MSSQLSERVER).
- Confirm in SQL Server Management Studio that `@@SERVERNAME` is now
  returning XXXXAT01.

Then the remote server itself was renamed to **XXXXAT01** by the network guys. And rebooted.

Now here is the issue:

I can make remote desktop connection to **XXXXAT01** and from inside I can open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to **XXXXAT01** server using Windows Authentication and run my queries.

But if open my local SQL Server Management Studio from my PC, and try to connect to **XXXXAT01** server using Windows Authentication, I get this error:

> Cannot connect to XXXXAT01.
>
> Additional information: The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot
>   generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server)

What could be the reason and what is the solution?

Comment: This is off-topic for SQ.  But this is a Kerberos error.  See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Comment: You probably need to delete the existing service principal names and create new ones.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver15